# User Control's dropdownlist select from added page with javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

i want user control's dropdownlist selected item from page. when i try to get dropdownlist id it doesn't return correct id. Have you any idea about what i can get dropdownlist id?

```
var e = $("#<%=ddlCategory.ClientID%> option:selected").val();

                 alert(e);
 <blogControl:UCCategory  ID="ddlCategory" runat="server"  />
```

Comment: Is *<blogControl:UCCategory />* a UserControl that contains a DropDownList? If so, you'd need to expose the UserControl's DropDownList ClientID, rather than the UserControl's ClientID. You could do this by putting a public read-only property in the UserControl that returns its DropDownList's ClientID, then use that in your jquery selector.

Answer (score 1):

i solve this problem to use this code,

**C#**

```
public string GetCategoryClientID()
{
    return   ddlCategory.ClientId;
}
```

**Js**

```
var e = document.getElementById("<%=GetCategoryClientID() %>");
alert(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
```